# What is this syntax #[] in REBOL?

Tags: rebol

In another question, I saw the following syntax:

`#[unset!]`

What is that? If I say `type? #[unset!]` in R3, it tells me `unset!`, but it doesn't solve the mystery of what `#[]` is.

So curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's the value-construction syntax for an unset instance, as opposed to the word `unset!`:

```
>> comparison: [unset! #[unset!]]
== [unset! unset!]

>> type? first comparison
== word!

>> type? second comparison
== unset!

>> second comparison
>> first comparison
== unset!
```

If you're in a programmatic context you could do this with `to-unset`, but having a literal notation lets you dodge the `reduce`:

```
>> comparison: reduce ['unset! to-unset none]
== [unset! unset!]

>> second comparison
>> first comparison
== unset!
```

Looks like they've reserved the #[...] syntax for more of these kinds of constructors.

Comment: BTW, check out some of my nuts Rebol-vs-Perl competition in Code Golf.  :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527477/code-golf-connecting-the-dots/3066878#3066878

Comment: It's getting easier, but here's one I did last night before that dot connection one that I got burned out on and didn't feel like pushing forward to the point of "winning"... sure these can be improved, if you want to play :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034331/code-golf-rotating-maze/3060396#3060396

Answer (score 6):

`#[]` is the serialized form for values. Play with MOLD versus MOLD/ALL in the console to get a feel for it.

Answer (score 4):

the `#[]` "syntax" is actually not a syntax as such (not legal syntax, if you try it), only special cases of such constructs are "legal", like the `#[unset!]` syntax, `#[true]` syntax, `#[false]` syntax, `#[none!]` syntax, or `#[datatype! unset!]` syntax.

What is even more interesting, is, what the `#[unset!]` value actually is. It happens to be the value every "uninitialized" variable in REBOL has (not in functions, though, function local variables are initialized to `#[none!]`), as well as the result of such expressions like `print 1`, `do []`, `()`, etc.

Regarding the "function local variables ... initialized to `#[none!]`" I should add, that only the variables following an "unused refinement" (i.e. the one not used in the actual call) are initialized to `#[none!]` together with the refinement variable.

To explain the issue further, the syntactic (Data exchange dialect) difference between `true` and `#[true]` is, that the former is a word, while the latter is a value of the logic! type. Seen from the semantic (Do dialect) point of view, the difference is smaller, since the (global) word is interpreted as a variable, which happens to refer to the `#[true]` value.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example below:

```
trace on
>> e: none
Trace:  e: (set-word)
Trace:  none (word) ;<<<<<

>> e: #[none]
Trace:  e: (set-word)
Trace:  none (none) ;<<<<<
```

`none` is a word in the first one, but in the second one, `#[none]` is not a word, it is the Rebol value of the datatype `none!`.
Similarly for other values like `true`, `false`. The `#[unset!]` case is special since every undefined variable actually has this value.